# cfwheels nestedproperties sortorder

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I'm trying to sort order records in nestedProperties of cfwheels. In nestedProperties, there is two records displayed in Create page. When I save these two records, the first record saved  as id = 2 (as second record) and the second record saved as (id = 1). When I displayed these two records in Edit page, id 1 display first and id 2 display 2. What I want is I want to display id 2 as first and id 1 as second by DESC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can set the sort order directly by column name: so:

```
users=model("user").findAll(
      include="addresses", order="users.lastname ASC, addresses.sortorder DESC");
```

Not tried it though!

Comment: Yap, I got it yesterday night also. Anyway, Thanks.